# How to mask out the input text in the google marketplace display file

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We want our solution to be listed in the Google Marketplace. It is pay-as-you-go, so user also has to contact our company to get the license, which includes serial number and password.
We have a display file that includes an input field for the password that the user received from us when the user types the password, I want that field to be masked with '.' so it is invisible.

I checked the documents from Google Marketplace, and I could not find any answer.

Here is the input field from the display file:

```
- name: vStreamPassword
  title: vSTREAM password
  section: LICENSE
```

I want something that describes the user input should be masked out.

Comment: Is this an add-on or a web app? Where do you have that display file?

Answer (score 0):

This display file is part of our Google cloud marketplace solution package which is required by Google, it describes all the input fields that the user will enter before he can create the VM. Our solution is Bring Your Own License, one field is asking user to type the license password which he received from us, and we want that field to display "." while he types just like when you type passwords.